# javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jsf-2.2, jexcelapi

In a *JSF 2.x* application, I'm using *PrimeFaces V-3.5* and *JasperReports V-5.2*. I am trying to export some reports with *JasperReports*. I am able to export report in *PDF* and *RTF* format; however, *Excel* format does not work and I encounter error as the following:

```
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/read/biff/BiffException
```

Here is my report generator method:

```
private void prepareReport(String reportPath, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List beanList, String outputFormat, String reportName) {
    JasperReport jReport = null;
    JasperPrint jPrint = null;
    try {
        jReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
        jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, jasperParameter, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beanList));
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF)) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".pdf");
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jPrint, outputStream);

        } else if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_EXCEL)) {
            response.setContentType("application/xls");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".xls");
            JExcelApiExporter exporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();

        } else if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_RTF)) {
            response.setContentType("application/rtf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".rtf");
            JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I export report in *Excel* format?

Comment: You should post the full stack trace

Comment: Did you add *jxl-2.6.10.jar* to classpath? You need this artifact: *net.sourceforge.jexcelapi.jxl:2.6.10* for *JasperReports 5.2*

Comment: I just added jxl-2.6.10.jar file and it is working. Thank you in advance. Make it as an answer so that I can vote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [*JExcelApiExporter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JExcelApiExporter.html). It is using the [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) library.

You can check the dependency in the *JasperReports*'s *pom.xml* file. The *JasperReports 5.2* is using this artifact:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.10</version>
</dependency>
```

It means that you should add *jxl-2.6.10.jar* to your application classpath (in case using *JasperReports 5.2*).